# Shift array forward in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, shift, alphabet

Okay, so I do not know if the title is right or not, but what I am struggling to do is find an algorithm to do something like this. So we have an input array such as: ['a','b', 'c', 'd', ...] until the end of the alphabet, and a number to shift with. I have to output the array like ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', ...] if I have a number 3 to shift with;
Any ideas on how to do it?
I tried:

```
function solve(args)
{
    let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    let number = 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (typeof arr[i + 1] === undefined)
        {
            arr[0] = arr[i];
        }
        else if (typeof arr[i - 1] === undefined)
        {
            arr[arr.length - 1] = arr[0];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access array in circular manner in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483149/how-to-access-array-in-circular-manner-in-javascript)

Comment: This is *rotating* the array, not shifting it.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost it except it prints `[d,e,f ... a,b,c]`

```
for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
   arr.push(arr.shift());
}
```

As pointed out in comments do this (thanks @dtkaias): Results in `[x,y,z,a,b,c...]`

```
for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
   arr.unshift(arr.pop());
}
```

The `unshift` function adds an element to the front of an array, while the `pop` function removes the last item, so it moves the last item to the front `number` times in the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't it be pop and unshift?

Comment: do `arr.unshift(arr.pop());` instead

Answer (score 4):

The tools you're looking for are `.slice` (
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice ), and
`.concat`
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat ).

```
function getShiftedArray (arr, n) {
    var i = arr.length - n;
    var front = arr.slice(0, i);
    var back = arr.slice(i);
    return back.concat(front);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that copies the result to a new array. Time and space complexity is `O(arr.length)`, if you are looking for a solution that mutates the array in place and has `O(x)` time complexity then see Patrick's answer.

```js
function rotate(arr, x) {
  return arr.slice(x).concat(arr.slice(0, x));
}

let arr = "abcdefghijkl".split("");

console.log(rotate(arr, -3).join(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

An invention of `Array.prototye.rotate()` might come handy for this job. Let's see a simple implementation.

```js
Array.prototype.rotate = function(n) {
                           var len = this.length;
                           return !(n % len) ? this.slice()
                                             : this.map((e,i,a) => a[(i + (len + n % len)) % len]);
                         };

var   alpha = Array(26).fill().map((_,i) => String.fromCharCode(i+97)),
 rotateLeft = e => (alpha = alpha.rotate(1), alphabet.textContent = alpha.join(",")),
rotateRight = e => (alpha = alpha.rotate(-1), alphabet.textContent = alpha.join(","));

alphabet.textContent = alpha.join(",");
buttonLeft.addEventListener("click",rotateLeft);
buttonRight.addEventListener("click",rotateRight);
```

```html
<div id="alphabet"></div>
<button id="buttonLeft"><<</button>
<button id="buttonRight">>></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the array in 2 parts and concat them afterwards. That's it!

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
number = 3;

xxx = arr.slice(-number);
yyy = arr.slice(0,arr.length - number);
arr_shift = xxx.concat(yyy);

console.log(arr_shift);
```