# How to start over when there are no more elements in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I "want" 6 elements from an array which only contains 3. If the end is reached, start over.

Example:

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let wanted = 5;

for(let i = 0; i < wanted; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Which of course returns:

```
a
b
c
undefined
undefined
```

Instead, I need:

```
a
b
c
a
b
```

Is there a way to start from the beginning of the array after the elements are over?

Comment: if arr[i] is undefined set i to 0. Simple!!

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: The loop would never stop then.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought of just resetting it but since the reset is happening in the loop, it never ends.

Comment: Not exact duplicate but similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483149/how-to-access-array-in-circular-manner-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get the remainder using [`%`(Remainder)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator.

```
console.log(arr[i % arr.length]);
```

The remainder value would be within the array index range.

For example: when `i` reaches to

- `3` => `3 % 3` = `0`
- `4` => `4 % 3` = `1`
- `0` => `0 % 3` = `0`.

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let wanted = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < wanted; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i % arr.length]);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is going on here?

Comment: Plus one for the answer, plus one again for calling % the remainder operator.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Just made you explanation as points. If not required, please revert it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**(%) remainder**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator. It will get index started from 0 till arr.length - 1.

First step is

```
[0 % 3] === 0 whole 0 remainder, 
[1 % 3] === 0 whole 1 remainder,
[2 % 3] === 0 whole 2 remainder
[3 % 3] === 1 whole 0 remainder
[4 % 3] === 1 whole 1 remainder
```

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let wanted = 5;

for(let i = 0; i < wanted; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i % arr.length]);
}
```

Comment: This is just a stolen answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/42828321/1990451

Comment: @smnbbrv And how are you sure ? If you will see my other answers you can find similar ones

Comment: by a timestamp?

Comment: if I can find similar ones might be that instead of answering you can mark the question as a duplicate instead of answering?

Comment: @smnbbrv I am not going to show or prove you anything. And there is noting to steel. If you name it steeling, so every answer after the first may be considered as a stolen answer. So have a good luck

Comment: @smnbbrv, What about [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) And 2 minute 18 sec

Comment: There are moderators. Write them

Comment: And istead of witch hunting comes with fact. as the version that include snippet and explanation and not a simple 'do this' came after this post.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `%`

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let wanted = 5;

for(let i = 0; i < wanted; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i % arr.length]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let wanted = 5;    

for (let i = 0; i < wanted; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    if (arr.length == i) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, this loop is infinite if `arr.length < wanted`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i+1 == arr.length){
 console.log(arr[i]);
 i=0;
 wanted =wanted-arr.length;
}else{
 console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

the loop will work normally until your counter is at the last element,
then it will be reset to 0 to start over and will keep doing this until you have reached your wanted number of elements.

Comment: what will this code do? Why will it solve, if it does. Please explain

Comment: Your code spells i in both upper and lowercase, and is lacking a for loop.

Comment: oh please give me a break, OP can add the snippet in their code no need to re-write his loop.