# Slice from beginning if array ended javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

So I'm working on some filters where users can select even from ex: "Friday to Tuesday" but how to I slice these from an array of dates

```
var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
```

So how do I slice from index from 5 to 2 which should return:

```
["friday", "saturday", "sunday", "monday", "tuesday"]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work so we can help you fix it.

Comment: This shows an example of treating the array in a circular manner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483207/11780044

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access array in circular manner in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483149/how-to-access-array-in-circular-manner-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You could make a simple function that tests whether the end is smaller than the start and slice accordingly:

```js
let days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

const wrapslice = (arr, start, end)  =>{
    return end < start 
    ? arr.slice(start).concat(arr.slice(0, end))
    : arr.slice(start, end)
}
console.log(wrapslice(days, 5, 2))
console.log(wrapslice(days, 2, 5))
console.log(wrapslice(days, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```js
var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

const selection = [...days.slice(4), ...days.slice(0, 2)];


console.log(selection);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Friday` is at index 4, so slice from index 4, and `.concat` with a slice of indicies 0 to 2:

```js
const arr = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
console.log(arr.slice(4).concat(arr.slice(0, 2)));
```