# How to allow a Time Interval with Bootstrap4 Date Time Picker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need to enable the hours based in this rule: Starting 1 hour from now and allow a range of 8 hours.

E.G, say now it's 13:00. So my picker should allow only hours between 14:00 - 22:00. If the current time its 21:00, it should allow 22:00 - 06:00.

Here's the code of my Date Picker:

```js
const datePicker = () => {
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    locale: 'PT-BR',
    icons: {
      up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
      down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
    },
    stepping: 15,
  });
};
```

I created some helper functions to get the edges.

```js
const hourStart = () => {
  const start = new Date();
  start.setHours(start.getHours() + 1);
  return start;
}

const hourFinish = () => {
  const finish = new Date()
  finish.setHours(hourStart().getHours() + 8);
  return finish;
}
```

I couldn't find anything in [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options) which allows set the enabled time interval, only the exact oposite [Disable Time Intervals](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals).

Maybe using the [Enabled Hours](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#endisabledhours) and some sort of Circular List?

There's any other way to achieve the expected behavior using this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using getTime instead of getHours:

```
const hadd = (d,h) => d.getTime()+(h*3600000);
const date0 = new Date('June 8, 2020 21:24:00');
console.log(date0);
console.log(new Date(hadd(date0,1)));
console.log(new Date(hadd(date0,9)));
```

should print (with your own Time zone):

```
// Mon Jun 08 2020 21:24:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
// Mon Jun 08 2020 22:24:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
// Tue Jun 09 2020 06:24:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to set on timepicker min and max

```js
const minHours = new Date().getHours() + 1;
const maxHours = new Date().getHours() + 8;
```

Comment: Please do not ask questions in answers. We try not to encourage discussions. If the question is unclear it means it should probably not be answered.

Comment: Added the picker