# How find if the current time exist in give time slots and find if the day is exist between given array of days

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is my days list

```
days_list: any[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      value: 'Monday'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      value: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      value: 'Thursday'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      value: 'Friday'
    }, {
      id: 5,
      value: 'Saturday'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      value: 'Sunday'
    },
  ]
```

Here is my Business Hours

```
business_hours = { day_to: 2, time_to: "23:00", day_from: 5, time_from: "08:00" }
```

I'm using UTC date format I want to know if the day from `days_list` exist according to `day_from` and `day_to`

For example here `day_from` is 5 which is Saturday and `day_to` is 2 Wednesday so the required array is:
`["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday". "Tuesday". "Wednesday"]` and the same for time if the current time exists in `time_from` and `time_to`,

My code is:

```
   const activationDate = new Date();

    const d_date = activationDate.getUTCDay() - 1;
    console.log(d_date);

    const B_from = this.getMin(this.business_hours.time_from);

    const B_To = this.getMin(this.business_hours.time_to);


    const min = activationDate.getUTCMinutes();
    console.log(min)
    const naan = activationDate.getUTCHours();
    console.log(naan)
    const utcTime = this.getUtcMin(naan, min);



    for(let j = 0; j < this.business_hours.day_to; j++) {
    for (let i = this.business_hours.day_from; i < this.days_list.length; i++) {
     
      console.log(this.days_list[i]);

      if (this.days_list[i].id === d_date) {
        this.is_open = true;
        console.log(this.days_list[i].value);
      }
     }
    }
```

it's not giving the required results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access array in circular manner in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483149/how-to-access-array-in-circular-manner-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is you'd like to treat your array as [*circular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), and then [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it according to a "from" and "to" index, where both the "from" and "to" indexes are treated as [inclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints).

Let's assume you have an array of strings like this:

```
console.log(dayArray);
// ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

(which you can turn your structure into easily enough like:

```
const dayArray = days_list.reduce<string[]>((a, d) => (a[d.id] = d.value, a), []);
```

)

Then you can write a circular array slice with inclusive endpoints function in any number of ways.  Here's one:

```
function circularArraySlice<T>(arr: T[], fromIndex: number, toIndex: number) {
  return arr.map((_, i, a) => a[(i + fromIndex) % a.length]).
    slice(0, ((arr.length + toIndex - fromIndex) % arr.length) + 1);
}
```

Essentially we're walking off the end of the array and back onto the beginning using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) as (almost) implemented by the [JS remainder operator (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).   Let's see if it works:

```
console.log(circularArraySlice(dayArray, 5, 2));
// ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"] 

console.log(circularArraySlice(dayArray, 2, 5));
// ["Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

This is, I think, what you want.  There may well be edge cases so be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQwJ4QPoBsCW0YF4YDaAUDDAN4mkyZwBcMADADSWkBuC6ArgKb0DkAWXCIk-SgF8WpClWp0YARmlUO3PjH4AVXhFHjSU8q3n0ATCvadeAgOo84YHnuQGYR2VRr0AzJZhqNppaABZcAE4uYpJMxnLeMAAs-oEa-ABi4TSuMXFeCgCsKdZpAMoIUBH6MZSepAkAbMXqAqVcYNWGLAC6ANxERKCQsKIAguHhyHjwyGhY0AB04Q5cwDwAPNBZYADmBN0AfAAURwixcACUeAcwpwRwCzTd0w+psQgXsfsX-UMQIOgeAt0CAdkcxhNkD8iAB6GGEABEwg6yARsQROmcojRMAR9kcWNR6NCESiOIRmWySHJ5Uq4Wx6LaKOpzwGADN2sAoJhwDBgJhwsAuOgEOFxpMkKUsGt1lpjqLwvQtPtYmzwiAALYASQ6PAAHvQwFwNQAjHjhWJQEA6uD6w3Gs3hK6eZZ0sAwBULDUIAAOJ1QsUw7yuuBuCAIR0wMAA1DA1ZqbfqrgBSD3Ani7KAhboXBYmCDSnhHZi3U4TdOZkIxmBWxN6mAAWjj6u1ur1KY95cBlauscU0IkAz+AKBILB-MFwtF4uQUswa3ByBnSFiRRgZgu0LhiNpVSJuKZDNxyKPGN0p-xTjJrMG4H+gOBoKOE6FIrFkMlhcXSGXsQsMAKTd+m3Ag8QcK9TxJSJT0pU9d3pVFuiIIA)

Answer (score 1):

To help answer questions like this, I'd recommend listing a couple of test cases and both provide expected values and the values you're actually seeing.

But I can see a couple of things which may cause problems in the code:

- The calculation of `d_date` is going to return -1 for Sunday, not 6 (like `days_list` is expecting)
- The outer loop (the one setting `j`) isn't really adding a lot here, because `j` isn't used inside the loop.  Therefore, each iteration of the loop is going to have the same effect.
- The inner loop (the one setting `i`) is only looking for days which appear after `day_from` in your `days_list` array.  However, as per you example, days from the start of `days_list` may also match if the `day_from` value is greater than `day_to`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Randy Casburn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9078341/randy-casburn)'s (now-deleted) answer, it's possible to solve this using javascript's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.
However, you need to be extra careful to handle separate cases for when `to_date` is before `from_date` and vice-versa.

For example:

```js
const days_list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

function getDays(business_hours) {
  const days = days_list.filter((_, id) => {
      if (business_hours.day_from <= business_hours.day_to) {
        return (id >= business_hours.day_from && id <= business_hours.day_to);
      } else {
        return (id <= business_hours.day_to || id >= business_hours.day_from);
      }
  })
  console.log(business_hours, days);
  return days;
}
getDays({ day_from: 2, time_from: "23:00", day_to: 5, time_to: "08:00"});
getDays({ day_to: 2, time_to: "23:00", day_from: 5, time_from: "08:00"});
getDays({ day_from: 3, time_from: "23:00", day_to: 3, time_to: "08:00"});
```